# Noticed your mail late or noticed your mail belatedly

Tags: expression-choice

A colleague send me a mail 2 days ago. I didn't notice it until today. How do I respond:-
(1) I noticed your mail late.
or
(2) I noticed your mail belatedly.

Comment: "I noticed your mail belatedly" sounds better to me, but what has led you to the conclusion that you can't use either one or that one is incorrect? [Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noticed+late%2C+noticed+belatedly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnoticed%20late%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnoticed%20belatedly%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Proofreading and writing advice questions do not help anyone but the asker. They are off topic unless there is a clearly identified source of concern which would be interesting to many future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer your description: "I didn't notice your email until today". Alternatively, "I just noticed your email." 
Note: If you have to choose between the two options, I'd go with number 2. "I noticed your mail late" doesn't flow. (and I would say email rather than mail, unless it is sent by post).

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go with "I didn't notice your email until today".

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "I somehow missed your email," and continue from there.

Betsy